# How to get Facebook timeline datas using Graph API by GET method?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I have to get Facebook time line feeds. Here I have used GET method to get details but the Facebook API has HTTPS instead of HTTP. The GET method accept only HTTP type url, and it HTTPS type URL gives null response. What will I do to get FB feeds.

```
 NSURLRequest *url_request=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString] cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSURLResponse *response_result;
NSError *Error;
NSData *result_data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:url_request returningResponse:&response_result error:&Error];
NSInteger statusCode = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response_result).statusCode;
NSLog(@"ST :%ld",(long)statusCode);
NSLog(@"Error :%@",Error);
Json_value=nil;
if (statusCode==200 && result_data) {
    Json_value = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result_data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&Error];
}
else{
    //         Json_value=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:Error.localizedDescription,@"errorValue", nil];
}
NSLog(@"JSONVALUE :%@",Json_value);
```

Comment: Are you sure GET only accepts HTTP, i am using HTTPS for communication even today, why dont you post your url string also. I am sure HTTPS is supported by NSURLConnection. But NSURLConnection is deprecated, try NSURLSession.